# detect return code (mode) in varnish hook

Tags: configuration, varnish, cache

In `vcl_recv` I decide whether to pass or lookup based on the existence of a cookie:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.Cookie ~ "(JSESSIONID=)" ) {
            /* do not cache logged in users */
            return (pass);
    }
    return (lookup);
}
```

In `vcl_fetch` I fine tune caching for some pages:

```
sub vcl_fetch {

    /* custom rules block */
    if (req.url ~ "^/foo") { set beresp.ttl=30s; }
    if (req.url ~ "^/bar") { set beresp.ttl=1m; }
    if (req.url ~ "^/123") { set beresp.ttl=10m; }

    return (deliver);
}
```

How can I know within `vcl_fetch` whether I am in pass or lookup mode? I'd like to be able to avoid running the "custom rules block" if I am in lookup mode because the logged in users will anyway run in pass mode so these rules do not apply to them.

Answer (score 2):

You can always set a custom header in vcl_recv:

```
sub vcl_recv {
  if (req.http.Cookie ~ "(JSESSIONID=)" ) {
    /* do not cache logged in users */
    set req.http.x-my-mark = "passed";
    return (pass);
  }
  return (lookup);
}
#...
sub vcl_fetch {
  if (req.http.x-my-mark == "passed") {
    /* custom rules block */
    if (req.url ~ "^/foo") { set beresp.ttl=30s; }
    if (req.url ~ "^/bar") { set beresp.ttl=1m; }
    if (req.url ~ "^/123") { set beresp.ttl=10m; }
  }

  return (deliver);
}
```

But I think it will be much cleaner to put your login on `vcl_pass`[1] or just perform your original check on vcl_fetch:

```
sub vcl_fetch {
  if (req.http.Cookie ~ "(JSESSIONID=)") {
    /* custom rules block */
    if (req.url ~ "^/foo") { set beresp.ttl=30s; }
    if (req.url ~ "^/bar") { set beresp.ttl=1m; }
    if (req.url ~ "^/123") { set beresp.ttl=10m; }
  }

  return (deliver);
}
```

[1] https://www.varnish-software.com/static/book/VCL_functions.html#vcl-vcl-pass